# MS Access Data criteria for a specific date

Tags: ms-access

```
< #2/2/2012#
```

This criteria "Returns items with a date before Feb 2, 2012.".

But how to do so when I run query to enter the date from the keyboard?

Something like this:
Enter date:--/--/----
And then return me the dates before the date that I entered.

Comment: You mean, like a [parameter query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-parameters-in-queries-and-reports-8209eb5c-1589-42e2-9b20-4181f4c7a356)?

Comment: @Gord Thompson Thank you. This solves the problem. I didn't know that there is such a thing as parameter query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the simple solution thanks to Gord Thompson.

First I set data type to date/time.

Then I made a query with criteria `<[Enter date]`.